# How to merge local folder and its structure to github?

Tags: github

I am still a beginner and I locally made a folder of my Project and uploaded it as a repository in GitHub using GitHubDesktop. Now I changed the structure of the files (deleted some sub-folders and moved files here and there locally). Now I don't see those changes in my GitHubDesktopas something which I can push to the GitHub online and reflect the changes there.

I am not sure how to achieve that:
(One way I can think is to reclone and download the online GitHub repository to local, move the changed files again and then commit from GitHubDesktop) , but I am not sure if it will work because I did the almost the same thing just without recloning: but after the reorganization, the changes are not appearing in my GitHubDekstop which I can commit.

Any advice would be great. Thank you.

This is my repository (https://github.com/grammilo/Codes) whose organization I want to copy from a local folder which goes by the same name and was previously cloned from it.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the directory of the repository in your terminal, checkout your master branch

```
git checkout master
```

and use

```
git diff
```

this will display any changes made to the files and file structure in green and red. You can delete folders and files directly from your file system or from the terminal, whichever you prefer and these changes will display when you use git diff. After your changes are made use

```
git add
```

this will stage your changes to be committed. You can use

```
git status
```

to make sure your changes are ones you would like to make.
Use

```
git pull
```

to pull any changes from your repository and when you are ready to commit your changes simply use

```
git push origin master
```

this will commit your changes to the remote repository on GitHub from your command line without using GitHub Desktop. Check out the git documentation for more in depth explanations but that should achieve what you're looking for.